# creating map file in r

Tags: r, genetics

I would like to prepare my dataset for analysis in the Plink program, but I have no idea on how to create the MAP and PED file.

I understand that I can create a PED file in R, but how do I create a MAP file in R?

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Give us a better description (and perhaps references) if what a MAP file is, please.